# Как сделать размытие в хедере?

Tags: html, css

[image: хедер]

Помогите стилизовать хедер. Не пойму, какие нужно свойства задавать в CSS?

Пока сделала так:

```
#header{ background-color: rgba(225, 221, 222, 0.9); box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(225, 221, 225, 0.9); }
```

Comment: Просто на фоне градиент с прозрачностью, наверное?

Comment: прикрепите ваш код, пожалуйста

Comment: #header{
    background-color: rgba(225, 221, 222, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(225, 221, 225, 0.9);
}

Comment: должно быть два слоя, один слой надо заблюрить...   `filter: blur(Npx);`

Comment: @Лина всё правильно сделали.

Comment: На картинке — то, что и должно получиться или то что получается, а вы хотели другое? Какое? Чтобы фото под #header было размыто? Тогда используйте backdrop-filter:blur(10px)

Comment: на картинке то, что должно получится

Comment: @Лина тогда background-color и box-shadow одного цвета — это и есть самый оптимальный вариант

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно при помощи [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient())

```css
body {
  background: #444;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, 
    rgba(255,255,255,1) calc(100% - 5px),
    rgba(255,255,255,1) calc(100% - 5px),
    rgba(255,255,255,0));
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Comment: Минус без причины - признак дурачины. Пишите хоть за что минус.

Comment: @DeMinov: думаю, что минус по причине большой содержательности ответа, на такой же содержательности вопрос. Вы же в курсе правил SO и знаете, что страницы индексируются для поиска. Тут нечего индексировать и, следовательно,  мало пользы - потому и минусанули.

Comment: огромное спасибо! вашим решением получилось приблизиться к тому, что есть на макете)

Comment: @Лина, не за что, если мой ответ помог, то отметьте его галочкой. Так же степень размытия редактируется `calc(100% - 5px)` меняя значение `5px`

Answer (score 0):

Помню мне тоже доводилось размывать фон, когда делал попап окно. Попробуйте сделать это через `svg`.

```css
html {
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/24/21/58/lemon-5435158_960_720.jpg")
    no-repeat fixed center / cover;
}

body {
  background: inherit;
}
.blur-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}

.blur-block:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: inherit;
  filter: blur(10px);
  filter: url(#blur);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-block" id="element"></div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="6"></feGaussianBlur>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Такой вариант длинный, но по крайней мере кроссбраузерный.

Comment: ТС не просит размыть изображение, см. иллюстрацию и комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: Тогда пусть у него стоит шапка сайта вместо изображения.

Comment: да, это не то решение(

Answer (score 0):

есть новые свойства css и они нормально работают:

```
#header { 
    background-color: rgba(225, 221, 222, .8);
    backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}
```

Comment: `нормально`, я б так не сказал - [поддержка свойства backdrop-filter](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter)

Comment: почему-то второе свойство не работает